# GeoTools and JOGL

Tags: jogl, geotools

I am developing a desktop application for Windows that will constantly show the map moving as a vehicle moves, getting the location from a GPS unit.  I have written a quick little demo that accomplishes this, however it constantly flickers.  I need to implement a solution that has a nice smooth movement.  I have several things in mind that will hopefully resolve this.

First I think it would be better to create the map at around 2 to 3 times the size of the visible window and move the window over the map.  When the window gets close to a side a new map is built in the background which replaces the current map.  I'm still working on how to do that.  (Hints welcome!!  lol)

I think it would be a big step forward and the ultimate solution to turn on hardware acceleration for the application.  Based on what I have read in the forums JOGL is the only practical way to add hardware acceleration to a Java desktop application.  So here I am.

Has anyone toyed around with adding JOGL to GeoTools.  I'm not talking about 3D at the moment, just making the display more efficient.  It looks like it's going to be a big job implementing this change as it appears that it will affect almost all of the code from JMapPane on down.  Any suggestions, code examples and hints will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the GLG2D project to render a Swing JComponent such as the JMapPane using hardware accelerated using JogAmp JOGL 2. This will allow you to use hardware acceleration with minimal changes to the GeoTools source.
http://brandonborkholder.github.io/glg2d/

```
JComponent renderPane = new JMapPane(...

JFrame frame = new JFrame("My GeoTools application");
frame.setContentPane(new GLG2DCanvas(renderPane));
...
```